# adding a route on sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am new in this situation. I create a route and controller. here is my code:

```
<?php
// /src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/MediaCRUDController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController;

class RatingController extends CRUDController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        eturn $this->render('CCApplicationBundle:Default:rating.html.twig');
    }
}
```

and my route:

```
admin_dashboard_rating:
  path:  /rating
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Rating:index }
```

Is there a way I can embed a link to the sonata admin?

Please help.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your `sonata_admin.yaml` config file:

```
    dashboard:
        groups:
            ...
            rating:
                on_top:         true
                label:          label.rating
                icon:           '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>'
                items:
                    - route:    admin_dashboard_rating
                      label:    rating
```